# Pythonにおける辞書型リストの呼び出し方についてです。

Tags: python, array

APIで取得した辞書型リストproduct_info[0]からproduct_info[6]のデータについて、それぞれproductとvolumeを表示させたいのですが、その表示がうまくいかずに悩んでいます。
辞書型リストにおけるprintでの指定の仕方はどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

```
# ※product_infoの中身はAPIで取得した内容をそのまま転記しております。
product_info=[]
product_info=[
'{"product":"hogeA","id":54,"volume":240}', 
'{"product":"hogeB","id":85,"volume":332}', 
'{"product":"hogeC","id":102,"volume":1023}',
 'none',
 'none',
 'none',
 'none'
]

for count in range(0,len(product_info)):
    if product_info[count] == 'none':
        print('売り切れ')
    else:
        print(product_info[count]['product','volume'])
```

Comment: 辞書のデータを文字列として格納する必要があるのでしょうか？3-5行目の `'{"product":"hogeA","id":54,"volume":240}', ` を直接 `{"product":"hogeA","id":54,"volume":240}, ` として辞書をリストに格納すればシンプルに解決できそうですが……

Comment: 説明が不足しており申し訳ございません。格納されたデータはAPIで取得していて、print(product_info)の結果が上記のとおり文字列でしたため、これをそのまま転記した次第です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 格納されたデータはAPIで取得

というところから、これは辞書型ではなくJSONデータのように見えます。このため、一旦JSONとしてパースすると良さそうです。

```
import json

# ...

for product in product_info:
    if product == 'none':
        print('売り切れ')
    else:
        product_info = json.loads(product)
        print(product_info['product'], product_info['volume'])
```

※ `in` 記法を利用し、不要な`count` 変数を削減しました